How in laravel make group by date of created_at field?
On laravel / mysql 8 site I need to get date where there are more rows by day with created_at datetime field With request :
$reactions = Reaction
    ::groupBy('created_at')
    ->orderBy('reaction_count', 'desc')
    ->select(
    'created_at',
        DB::raw('count(created_at) as reaction_count'))
    ->get();

I trace sql I see wrong counting(as time is calculated)
SELECT `created_at`, count(created_at)     AS reaction_count
    FROM `reactions`
    GROUP BY `created_at`
    ORDER BY `reaction_count` desc

I try to remake sql-statement as :
SELECT created_at, count(CAST(created_at AS DATE))     AS reaction_count
FROM reactions
GROUP BY reaction_count
ORDER BY reaction_count desc
but error raised :
SQL Error [1056] [42000]: Can't group on 'reaction_count'

I have a similar error with request:
In which way have I to remade sql and laravel request to work properly ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.12",
“8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1”

Thanks in advance!

does this works on your db as expected? SELECT DATE(created_at) as date, count(*) as reaction_count FROM reactions GROUP BY DATE(created_at) ORDER BY reaction_count DESC;
